# How to run some specific code before evaluating .val() for every input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to override the `.val()` attribute of an input.

For example, before jQuery gets the value when `.val()` is called, run some code like stripping HTML tags.

Comment: What does that code do?

Comment: Explain what you wanna achieve and show the code to understand the same.

Comment: strips html tags. there are a lot of input boxes but it will be cumbersome to manipulate every value

Comment: "a code" and "another code" are grammatically incorrect. See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/209724/97308).

Comment: `.val` is not an attribute of an input. It's a jQuery method, and of course you can override that do your bidding by `$.fn.val = …`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Definitely, but I won't really recommend it, unless you really want to do some mad science on the page (such as adding some custom proxies to interfere with code you cannot control). Instead, you can create your own function by appending it to the `$.fn` object (see below).

#### Override

Still, if you really want to override it, here is how: just override the `$.fn.val` method:

```js
var $input = $("input")

// Before overriding
console.log($input.val())

// Override
//  1. Create a copy of the function
const oldValFn = $.fn.val
$.fn.val = function () {

  // 2. Run your custom code
  console.log("Called val");

  // 3. Call the native jQuery
  //    function and return the result
  return oldValFn.apply(this, arguments);
};


// After overriding
console.log($input.val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="42" />
```

#### Create a *new* function

Instead of *overriding*, you can create a *custom `val`* (basically, a small plugin):

```js
var $input = $("input")

$.fn.customVal = function () {

  var value = this.val();

  // Run your custom code
  //    e.g. append some data
  value = "The value is: " + value

  
  return value;
};

// Call it
console.log($input.customVal())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="42" />
```

Comment: Can you not write your own function .stripHtmlBeforeVal() and call that function instead of changing original val(). Inside that, you can call function to strip HTML and call val() function.

Comment: @Amit That's what I just did. I don't recommend overriding `val`.

Comment: Yup, this one's much better. :-)

Comment: there are a lot of input boxes in the project. imagine me going through all the files and folders and calling `.stripTags` on all of them @Amit

Comment: @Tushortz It's probably safer to *replace all `.val(` with `.stripTags(`* (in your files) than proxying the `val` method (which is used in other scripts as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `val()` with a callback, modify the value inside the callback, and then call `val()` to get the modified value.

Example stripping HTML tags from inputs

```js
$('#test').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val(function(_, v) {   // use a callback
    return $('<div />', { html: v }).text(); // strips HTML and returns result
  }).val();                                  // gets modified value

  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Type some HTML in the input</p>
<br />
<input id="test">
```